# ¿Cómo podría detectar que un usuario ha salido de mi web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

lo que estoy intentando es hacer un contador de tiempo y que cuando salgan de mi web (por ejemplo hacia google) pare ese contador y que dependiendo de los segundos se le asigne un tag u otro, pero lo que llevo hecho no detecta el cambio de url.
Dejo aquí el code ACTUALIZADO:

```
   <script> 

window.addEventListener("unload", function(event) { 



        var dust = "coffe2";

       if (n <= 10){
    var type_of_user = "missclicked user or crawler";


    }
    else{

    }
    if(n <= 6){
        var type_of_user = "potential crawler";
    }
    else{

    }
    if (n => 30 ){
        var type_of_user = "potential customer";

    }
    else{

    }
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./assets/php/app.php",
                data: { dust: dust, ip_f: localStorage.getItem("ip_f"), b: localStorage.getItem("time"), type_of_user: type_of_user }
            }).done(function (msg) {
                console.log("Los datos que se recibieron: " + msg);
            });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Los cambios de URL son detectados solo cuando te mantienes en el mismo sitio, al cargar otro, el navegador deja de ejecutar ese script. En todo caso investiga sobre los eventos `onunload` y `onbeforeunload` (experimental).

Comment: @Triby Hola! Acabo de probar con onunload en body, pero sin embargo no ha funcionado, ¿qué puede ser? No da ningún error en la consola, actualizo el code

Comment: ¿Revisaste la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload)? Prueba asignando el evento a la ventana y no a una etiqueta del documento, de preferencia, con `window.addEventListener()`

Comment: Hola de nuevo @Triby! Acabo de realizar los cambios pertinentes, pero cuando cierro la pestaña o el navegador sigue sin ejecutarse el código de AJAX.
Vuelvo a modificar la pregunta con el nuevo código

Comment: Destaco que no estoy usando iframes, lo estoy usando para que cuando el usuario cierre la página, ya bien sea mediante cerrando la pestaña o mediante cerrando el navegador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He logrado satisfacer mis necesidades a través del siguiente código:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {

 var n = localStorage.getItem("time");
    var dust = "coffe2";

       if (n <= 10){
    var type_of_user = "missclicked user or crawler";


    }
    else{

    }
    if(n <= 6){
        var type_of_user = "potential crawler";
    }
    else{

    }
    if (n >= 30 ){
        var type_of_user = "potential customer";

    }
    else{

    }
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "./assets/php/app.php",
                data: { dust: dust, ip_f: localStorage.getItem("ip_f"), b: localStorage.getItem("time"), n: n, type_of_user: type_of_user }
            }).done(function (msg) {
                console.log("Los datos que se recibieron: " + msg);
            });

});
```

Lo que hace es que al cerrar la website se ejecuta todo lo de abajo.